# Cycle CUDA Viewport GTX 1060 Mobile and Quadro M600M

Tags: 3d-view

my question is not about hardware comparison but CUDA.

I have two works station:

- A MSI Laptop , with GTX 1060, I7 and 32Go of Ram
- A Wacom mobilestudio Pro, with Quadro M600M, I5 and 8Go of Ram

Running Windows 10, and CUDA is active on Cycle Compute Device and GPU Compute too on both. Of course, same version of Blender 2.79

Yesterday, I used my Wacom for texturing and has loaded the scene I worked on. When I switched to rendered mode in viewport, it tooks forver to reach the preview samples set on my scene (which was 64)

THen, I notice, that on the Wacom with the quadro, with a sample of 8 or 12, the result is less noisy and more precise than with my laptop even if this one is set to 64 samples, does it means that with my Quadro I don t need to have high sample value for my viewport preview ?

Any ideas, why is there such a difference on time calculation, and such a quality difference ?

Thank you